# Checking existence of data by make, model, and year range

Tags: php, laravel

I am receiving inputs for 'make', 'model', 'fromyear', and 'toyear' from the user. I want to prevent the user from entering a 'fromyear' and 'toyear' range that already exists in the database for the given 'make' and 'model'.

For example, if there is a record in the database with 'make' as 'Toyota', 'model' as 'Camry', 'fromyear' as 2015, and 'toyear' as 2020, then the user should not be allowed to enter the following ranges:

- 2016 to 2017
- 2016 to 2018
- 2019 to 2022
- 2013 to 2016

However, if the 'fromyear' and 'toyear' do not fall within any existing range in the database, then the user should be allowed to enter them.

The database table has columns named 'make', 'model', 'fromyear', and 'toyear'.

```
$has_range = PartsList::where('make', $request->make)
    ->where('model', $request->model)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereBetween('fromyear', [$request->fromyear, $request->toyear])
            ->orWhereBetween('toyear', [$request->fromyear, $request->toyear]);
    })
    ->exists();

if ($has_range) {
    $msg = 'year range already exists for this make and model';
}
```

Comment: Laravel is a PHP framework. Your code is also PHP. Why is this tagged as [tag:javascript]??

Comment: what's the problem with your code? looks fine to me

Comment: Are you having a specific issue? Please clarify. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your problem

Comment: this code accepting like fromyear 2021 and toyear 2021 but its falling in a range where data is already in db with the range fromyear 2020 toyear 2025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that any kind of overlap is caught, you need to adjust your logic to consider all possible overlap scenarios:

1. The user's fromyear is within any existing range.
2. The user's toyear is within any existing range.
3. The user's range entirely encompasses an existing range.
4. An existing range entirely encompasses the user's range.

Here's how you can adjust your query to cover all these cases:

```
$has_range = PartsList::where('make', $request->make)
    ->where('model', $request->model)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        // Case 1: User's fromyear is within an existing range.
        $query->where(function($q) use ($request) {
            $q->where('fromyear', '<=', $request->fromyear)
              ->where('toyear', '>=', $request->fromyear);
        })
        // Case 2: User's toyear is within an existing range.
        ->orWhere(function($q) use ($request) {
            $q->where('fromyear', '<=', $request->toyear)
              ->where('toyear', '>=', $request->toyear);
        })
        // Case 3: User's range encompasses an existing range.
        ->orWhere(function($q) use ($request) {
            $q->where('fromyear', '>=', $request->fromyear)
              ->where('toyear', '<=', $request->toyear);
        })
        // Case 4: An existing range encompasses the user's range (this might actually be redundant given the first two checks, but added for clarity).
        ->orWhere(function($q) use ($request) {
            $q->where('fromyear', '<=', $request->fromyear)
              ->where('toyear', '>=', $request->toyear);
        });
    })
    ->exists();

if ($has_range) {
    $msg = 'The year range already exists for this make and model.';
}
```

Comment: This adjusted logic more thoroughly checks for any kind of overlap between the user's input and existing ranges in the database, ensuring that any conflicting range is detected. It considers all scenarios of overlap, making your validation logic more robust.